# Redefining figure* for Beamer

Tags: beamer, environments

I have a single `figure*` graphic in a separate file (let's just call this `x.tex`). This file is shared across several latex documents and is inserted with `input` for each document.

Unfortunately, when I try to insert this in a Beamer slide document with `\input{x}`, Beamer chokes and says `Environment figure* undefined`.

I've tried fooling around with `newenvironment` but I don't know enough about it to create a new definition for `figure*`.

What's the simplest way to insert this file in a Beamer document without having to modify the file being inserted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `beamer` doesn't define a `figure*` environment, you should be able to create one yourself:

```
\newenvironment{figure*}%
{\begin{figure}}
{\end{figure}}
```

This simply says to create an environment `figure*` which is identical to the `figure` environment.

Comment: Thanks! It was the syntax of `newenvironment` that I couldn't figure out.

Comment: @Jason It's basically `\newenvironment{name}{stuff at the beginning}{stuff at the end}`. (Starred *macros* can't be created the same way, however.)